# ScrollToTop exibits odd behaviors when using jQuery .animate

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate

I am trying to implement Scroll To Top functionality on a website. The script works as expected when I simply fade the button in and out like so ...

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery("#top").hide();
    jQuery(function toTop() {
        jQuery(window).scroll(function () {
            if (jQuery(this).scrollTop() > 100) {
                jQuery('#top').fadeIn();
            } else {
                jQuery('#top').fadeOut();
            }
        });

        jQuery('#top').click(function () {
            jQuery('body,html').animate({
                scrollTop: 0
            }, 1200);
            return false;
        });
    });         
   });
```

```css
div.wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  height: 2500px;
  }
  
#top {
    background-image:url("https://blindspotetc.com/wp-content/uploads/2022/11/icon-up.png");
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
        position: fixed;
        width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    bottom: 5%;
    cursor: pointer;
      opacity: 1;
        z-index: 99;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.4.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
<p>
Scroll down to test.</p>

<a onclick="toTop()" id="top" class="back-to-top" title="Go to top"></a>
</div>
```

However, when I add jQuery animate methods the behavior becomes erratic ...

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery("#top").hide();
    jQuery(function toTop() {
        jQuery(window).scroll(function () {
            if (jQuery(this).scrollTop() > 200) {
                jQuery('#top').fadeIn().animate({left:'90%'});
            } else {
                jQuery('#top').animate({left:'10%'}).fadeOut();
            }
        });

        jQuery('#top').click(function () {
            jQuery('body,html').animate({
                scrollTop: 0
            }, 1200);
            return false;
        });
    });         
            
            
    
    });
```

```css
div.wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  height: 2500px;
  }
  
#top {
    background-image:url("https://blindspotetc.com/wp-content/uploads/2022/11/icon-up.png");
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
        position: fixed;
        width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    bottom: 5%;
    cursor: pointer;
      opacity: 1;
        z-index: 99;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.4.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
<p>
Scroll down to test.</p>

<a onclick="toTop()" id="top" class="back-to-top" title="Go to top"></a>
</div>
```

The button shows up and animates but only if you scroll to the bottom of the div twice. It also does not animate back as expected when you scroll back up. In addition, scrolling down a third or fourth time the button does not show up again.

I am sure that I am doing something wrong but I can not find a solution. I have tried using `marginLeft` as opposed to `left` to no avail.

Does anyone know what is going on here? I'm completely at a loss.

Answer (score 0):

I have encountered the same problem sometimes, this is the solution I found in the internet. Simple and short code.

```
(function($) {
  "use strict"; // Start of use strict

  

  // Scroll to top button appear
  $(document).on('scroll', function() {
    var scrollDistance = $(this).scrollTop();
    if (scrollDistance > 100) {
      $('.scroll-to-top').fadeIn();
    } else {
      $('.scroll-to-top').fadeOut();
    }
  });

  // Smooth scrolling using jQuery easing
  $(document).on('click', 'a.scroll-to-top', function(e) {
    var $anchor = $(this);
    $('html, body').stop().animate({
      scrollTop: ($($anchor.attr('href')).offset().top)
    }, 1000, 'easeInOutExpo');
    e.preventDefault();
  });

})(jQuery); // End of use strict
```

Then in HTML,

```
<a class="scroll-to-top rounded" href="#page-top">
   <i class="fas fa-angle-up"></i>
</a>
```

Comment: Thanks, Nagonus. Unfortunately, while your solution works with `fadeIn` and `fadeOut`, once I add `.animate({left:'90%'})` and `({left:'10%'})` the behavior is still erratic. Here is your code with animation added:

Comment: Sorry. Thanks, Nagonus. Unfortunately, while your solution works with `fadeIn` and `fadeOut`, once I add `.animate({left:'90%'})` and `.animate({left:'10%'})` the behavior is still erratic.

Comment: Try adding a style in your div, it might solve your problem, ```<div class='wrapper' style='position: absolute !important;'>Content</div>``` or any position properties such as relative... hope it works

Comment: Hi Nagonus, That does not help either. Besides, we are talking about a scroll-to-top function. This would mean I would be setting the body tag to absolute.

Comment: I don't think you have to set the body to absolute, instead set it in a relative position and an absolute position to the scroll-to-top element... but we'll know if it that's a case